# Stuck on best friends function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently doing a project where users will receive +2 points for every message they have sent and +5 for every picture they have sent. At the very moment, I'm busy with the profile page of the users. I have a box where I'd like to show, based on the points, the 3 best friends of that user.

I also got a friend_request feature as users have the possibility to lock their accounts for the public, so only approved friends can see whatever they up to. So what I did was, I added a 'points' column to the friends table in my database, since I'll be checking for the best friends.

But now I'm kinda stuck.. My current version of the code only checks the 'friend_two' users and rank in on the highest > lowest amount of points. The problem is that I CAN BE friend_two instead of 'friend_one' and someone else CAN BE 'friend_one' instead of 'friend_one' depending on whoever has invited the other one.

How can I archive it like this, so that it checks both columns instead of only the 'friend_two' column?

**My get_bestFriends() function:**

```
/// BEST FRIENDS FUNCTION - lIMITED TO 3
function get_bestFriends($mysqli, $username) {

    //Get the visiting profiles username
    $username = safe($mysqli,$_GET["username"]);

    //Get all friends out of the database and put it into an array
    $showBestFriends = array(); 
    $getBestFriends = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE ((friend_one = '$username') OR (friend_two = '$username')) AND invited = '1' AND accepted = '1' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($getBestFriends) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getBestFriends)){
            $row = array( 'friend_one' => $row['friend_one'], 
            'friend_two' => $row['friend_two'], 
            'points' => $row['points'] );
            $showBestFriends[] = $row;
        } 

        //Start displaying the arrays content
        foreach ($showBestFriends as $stt):

        //Get the avatars of the three best friends
        $getBestFriendsAvatar = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT avatar FROM members WHERE username = '".$stt['friend_two']."' ") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $ava = mysqli_fetch_array($getBestFriendsAvatar);
        $avatarURLf = $ava['avatar'];

            echo '<div class="best-friend">';
            echo '<div class="profileContentBox_avatar">';
            echo '<img id="user-avatar" data-title="SHOW USERINFO" title="Avatar from '.$username.'" src="'.$ava['avatar'].'" class="profileContentBox_avatar thumbnail-small" draggable="false">';
            echo '<div class="profileContentBox_messages">'.$stt['points'].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="profileContentBox_username">'.$stt['friend_two'].'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

        endforeach;

    } else {
        //There are currently no (best) friends yet
        echo '<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 9pt;">No best friends found</div>';

    }
}
```

I simply show the them by echoíng the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalise your data, so the system can treat the "friend relation" more generally, and so you don't need to add more columns if you want users to be able to have more friends.

Try using this database structure:

```
user
---
id (int)                 } primary key
name (varchar)

friend_of
---
from_user_id (int, fk)   } primary key
to_user_id (int, fk)     } primary key
is_invited (bool)
is_accepted (bool)
```

You could also delete `is_invited` - in this normalised form, `is_accepted` is sufficient on its own. False means invited and true means accepted.

To get all the friends of a particular user, you can do this:

```
SELECT
    user.*
FROM friend_of fo
INNER JOIN user ON (fo.to_user_id = user_id)
WHERE
    fo.from_user_id = 123 /* This is the 'from' user */
    AND fo.is_accepted = true
```

Comment: I have never ever used JOIN before, lmfao. But I think I might have solved it via an other way. Alot of more code though. Check my edited question if you want to :) THanks for your effort though!

Comment: Woops! Edited now ^^ - As you can see, I checked whether the friend_one was NOT equal to the profiles username. If it's not equal, it does the query I want it to do. If it is equal, it goes on to the second, which does the same thing but the other way around.

Comment: Great. However, we tend to discourage answers in questions, as it is confusing for API users as well as future readers - would you roll that back and paste it in as a self-answer? Also, the normalised approach is still better - do look into it when you get a mo!

Comment: Sorry about that, will do when I hit the 10 rep, otherwise over 8 hours. I will look into your question as it seems alot better indeed. I'm not that skilled yet, still figuring out you know :) One quick offtopic question though, if thats okay: Should I also prepare SELECT statements? I usually only prepare whenever an user submits info to the database? Thanks again!

Comment: Preparing statements isn't essential. It's good for two reasons: if you wish to execute a statement many times (i.e. benefit from the query cache) or you have input parameters to inject (especially tainted values). If you have a query to be run once with safe/hardwired params, you can execute it without preparation.

Answer (score 0):

Might have solved it, final code:

```
// BEST FRIENDS FUNCTION - LIMITED TO 3
function get_bestFriends($mysqli, $username) {

    //Get the visiting profiles username
    $username = veilig($mysqli,$_GET["username"]);

    //Get all friends out of the database and put it into an array
    $showBestFriends = array(); 
    $getBestFriends = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE ((friend_one = '$username') OR (friend_two = '$username')) AND invited = '1' AND accepted = '1' ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($getBestFriends) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getBestFriends)){
            $row = array( 'friend_one' => $row['friend_one'], 
            'friend_two' => $row['friend_two'], 
            'points' => $row['points'] );
            $showBestFriends[] = $row;
        } 


        //Start displaying the arrays content
        foreach ($showBestFriends as $stt):

        //Get the avatars of the three best friends

            //CHECK IF THE $USERNAME IS NOT EQUAL TO FRIEND_ONE. 
            if ($stt['friend_one'] != $username){

                $getBestFriendsAvatar = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT avatar FROM members 
                WHERE username = '".$stt['friend_one']."' ") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
                $ava = mysqli_fetch_array($getBestFriendsAvatar);
                $avatarURLf = $ava['avatar'];

            } else if ($stt['friend_two'] != $username) {

                $getBestFriendsAvatar = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT avatar FROM members 
                WHERE username = '".$stt['friend_two']."' ") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
                $ava = mysqli_fetch_array($getBestFriendsAvatar);
                $avatarURLf = $ava['avatar'];
            }

            echo '<div class="best-friend">';
            echo '<div class="profileContentBox_avatar">';
            echo '<img id="user-avatar" data-title="SHOW USERINFO" title="Avatar from '.$username.'" src="'.$ava['avatar'].'" class="profileContentBox_avatar thumbnail-small" draggable="false">';
            echo '<div class="profileContentBox_messages">'.$stt['points'].'</div>';

            //TEST
            if ($stt['friend_one'] != $username){
            echo '<div class="profileContentBox_username">'.$stt['friend_one'].'</div>';
            } else if ($stt['friend_two'] != $username) {
                echo '<div class="profileContentBox_username">'.$stt['friend_two'].'</div>';
            }

            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

        endforeach;

    } else {
        //There are currently no (best) friends yet
        echo '<div style="text-align: center; font-size: 9pt;">No best friends found</div>';

    }
}
```